# Entity Framework: Inherit from Custom DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, dbcontext

Is it possible to inherit a custom DBContext and then modify the entities of the inherited context has without modifying the base tables with discriminator columns?

```
public class BaseDbContext: DbContext {
    public IDbSet<BaseClass> BaseClasses { get; set; }
}

public class BaseClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    etc...
}

public class NewDbContext: BaseDbContext {
    public IDbSet<NewBaseClass> NewBaseClasses { get; set; }
}

public class NewBaseClass: BaseClass {
    public string SomePropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a project that is setup for a base database structure use the BaseDbContext. If I created a new database with the same schema and added a column to the BaseClasses table called SomePropertyName. I want to create a new DbContext that derives from the BaseDbContext, and then add the extra property to the new class, NewBaseClass.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered not using an inherited DbContext but instead making your data classes partial classes?  I believe this will allow you to extend the data classes in a new project.

Comment: Yes, I have considered this; however, what I'm aiming for would need the inherited DbContext in a separate project. Partial classes would not work. I want to be able to replace existing models with new ones that have extra properties.